# Logistic regression Macro

Tags: macros, sas, logistic-regression

```
    %macro intercept(i1= ,i2= );
      %let n = %sysfunc(countw(&i1));

       %do i = 1 %to &n;
          %let val_i1 = %scan(&i1,&i,'');
          %let val_i2 = %scan(&i2,&i,'');
          data scores;
            set repeat_score2;
            /* Segment 1 probablity score  */
            p1 = 0;
            z1 =   &val_i1      +
                    a         *      0.03            +
                    r         *    -0.0047841        +
                    p         *   -0.000916081      ;

            p1 = 1/(1+2.71828**-z1);

            /* Segment 2 probablity score  */
           p2 = 0;
           z2 =   &val_i2           +
                   r           *       0.09           +
                   m           *     0.012786245      +
                   c           *    -0.00179618        +
           p2 = 1/(1+2.71828**-z2);

           logit_score = 0;
           if max(p1,p2) =      p1 then logit_score = 1;
           else if max(p1,p2) = p2 then logit_score = 2;
         run;

         proc freq data = scores;
            table logit_score * clu_ /nocol norow nopercent;
         run;
    %end;
  %mend;
%intercept (i1=-0.456491042, i2=-3.207379842, i3=-1.380627318 , i4=0.035684096, i5=-0.855283373);
%intercept (i1=-0.456491042 0, i2=-3.207379842 -3.207379842, i3=-1.380627318 -1.380627318, i4=0.035684096 0.035684096,
            i5=-0.855283373 -0.855283373);
```

I have the above macro which takes the intercept for the two of the above models and then calculates the probablity score and then assigns a a value to to a segment based on that probablity score.

The first problem with above macro is when I execute the macro with one argument each it's resolving macro variable 'n' to 2 and executing twice. First iteration, it's giving the right results while for second it's wrong.

For the second implementation(macro with two aruguments each) n is resolving to 3 and scan is resolving to both of those values together at a time (eg. i1 for the iteration itself is -0.45 and 0), If I remove the space, then it taking '.' to be the delimiter and resolving that to ( 0,45,0 - one for each iteration). I don't get any results for this case.

How do I get this to work the right way?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm also going to offer a suggestion - put parameters into a dataset and pass them as a dataset. Let your macro loop over the rows of the dataset instead of multiple macro variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%SCAN` and `COUNTW` function by default consider punctuation symbols and blanks as delimiters. Since your arguments include decimal points, you need to state explicitly that delimiter should be blank for both `COUNTW` and `%SCAN`. Which you have done for `%SCAN`, but not for `COUNTW`.
So the 2nd line of the code should be:

```
 %let n = %sysfunc(countw(&i1,' '))
```

And I'm not sure if it's a typo or just formatting thing, but in your %SCAN functions third argument looks like two quotes together `''`, not quote-blank-quote `' '` as it should be.